# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native)

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to log my users into my application using passport. I am getting the following error when trying to serialize the user. It is saying I have a circular structure, but I do not believe I do.

Has anyone had this occur?

```
{ _id: 584633e911d8450dbccb4628,
  username: 'mloomis',
  email: 'loomis.m@husky.neu.edu',
  password: '$2a$10$wz5M3rURmihkXlG.AQ68QO3h0gYhdvBwa/JTKJuFSS24EnC4/4Rpy',
  __v: 0,
  fitnessGoal: 'Loose Weight',
  heightInches: 5,
  heightFeet: 5,
  weight: 150,
  lastName: 'Loomis',
  firstName: 'Mallory',
  img: 'upload/myFile-1480996068801.jpeg',
  dateCreated: Mon Dec 05 2016 22:43:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
  messages: [],
  trainers: [],
  favoriteRecipes: [] }
```

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at Object.stringify (native)
>       at stringify (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1064:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\express\lib\response.js
>   :243:14)
>       at clientLogin (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\project\services\client.service.server.js:10
>   5:13)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\express\li
>   b\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at complete (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authentica
>   te.js:250:13)
>       at C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:257:
>   15
>       at pass (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:421:14)
>       at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\li
>   b\authenticator.js:443:5)
>       at C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:254:
>   22
>       at C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:60:7
>       at pass (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:267:43)
>       at serialized (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:27
>   6:7)
>       at serializeClient (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\project\services\client.service.server.j
>   s:85:9)
>       at pass (C:\Users\mloomis\neu\webdev\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:284:9)

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    weight: Number, 
    heightFeet: Number, 
    heightInches: Number,
    fitnessGoal: {type: String, enum: ['Loose Weight', 'Maintain Weight', 'Gain Weight']},
    img: String,
    favoriteRecipes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'RecipeModel'
    }],
    trainers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TrainerModel'
    }],
    messages: [{
        message: String,
        trainer: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'TrainerModel'
        }
    }],
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
    }, {collection: "client"})
```

;

```
function localStrategy(username, password, done) {
    model
        .clientModel
        .findClientByUsername(username)
        .then(
            function (client) {
                if (client && bcrypt.compareSync(password, client.password)) {
                    if (!client) { 
                        return done(null, false); 
                    }
                    return done(null, client);
                } else {
                    res.send('0');
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                res.sendStatus(400).send(error);
            }
        );
}

function serializeClient(client, done) {
    console.log(client);
    done(null, client);
}
```

Comment: can you show your local authentication strategy and how you are serializing the user? This might help us to solve the issue.

Comment: @ravishankar I added my local strategy and serialize function